# mysql syntax-error on query

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error

Heres a snapshot of my database: http://postimg.org/image/p3hj9pw3n/

I have this problem regarding this mysql query syntax :

```
 SELECT a.examid        AS ei,
       a.examname      AS en,
       f.subtitle      AS st,
       b.day           AS d,
       b.timestart     AS ts,
       b.timeend       AS te,
       c.attemps       AS a,
       d.employeelname AS ln,
       d.employeefname AS fn,
       d.employeemname AS mn
FROM   exams a,
       examsched b,
       scores c,
       employees d,
       students e,
       subjectlist f
WHERE  a.examid = b.exams_examid
       AND a.examid = c.exams_examid
       AND a.employees_empid = d.empid
       AND c.students_studnum = e.studnum
       AND a.subjectlist_subcode = f.subcode
ORDER  BY b.day
```

It displays this kind of error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.examid = b.exams_examid AND a.examid = c.exams_examid AND a.employees_empid = ' at line 1`

I hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be so kind and clean up your posting.

Comment: What do you mean by this 'kind' of error. Either this is the error - or it isn't!

Comment: Are you sure there's not a space missing between keywords? Sometimes php formatting is confusing

Comment: There is no space missing.

Comment: This displays this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.examid = b.exams_examid AND a.examid = c.exams_examid AND a.employees_empid = ' at line 1

Comment: i have updated the post with snapshot of the database.

Comment: @user3261664 have you executed the code above at once or in parts? Because it says at line 1 and I would have guested that this would have been much higher at line 17.

Comment: @user3261664 execute the code above in one go.

Comment: It really is a 1 line code, stack overflow only formats it.
Heres a snapshot.
http://postimg.org/image/l0nkxyhg7/

Comment: Have you tried executing the code directy through the MySQL command line? B.T.W. you could try to add `AS` in between the table name and abbreviation, e.g. change `exams a` into `exams AS a`.

Comment: @user3261664 this type of syntax error is likely to occur when you made a mistake in the line just before the a.examid ... . Most likely you have missed a comma just before in the FROM Clause. However, you code doesn't show this problem so this is strange. Could you post the table structure of you question in a SQL format. With `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and some sample data to test.